# React Native Elements hide bottom of card image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working with a card of react native elements and i'm trying to hide the bottom of the card (because is a space blank). Well i dont if is a footer or bad sizing. I'm  new with react native and style and i dont know if you can disable or hide like CSS in web page. Sorry for the dumb issue but i dont have a clear idea! Thanks for any help!!

So this is my card view:

```
 return(
        <ScrollView style={{

          }}>

            <Image
                source={this.state.imagenes[posicion]}  
                resizeMode={'cover'}
                style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }}
            />

            <View style={styles.ProductosCategoriaPadre}>
              <View style={{ width: '50%'}}>
              <Card
                title='STACKOVERFLOW'
                image={require('../imagenes/imagen4.jpg')}
              >
              </Card>

              </View>

              <View style={{ width: '50%'}}>

              <Card
                title='STACKOVERFLOW'
                image={require('../imagenes/imagen2.jpg')}
              >
              </Card>

              </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.ProductosCategoriaPadre}>
              <View style={{ width: '50%'}}>
              <Card
                title='STACKOVERFLOW'
                image={require('../imagenes/imagen2.jpg')}
              >
              </Card>

              </View>

              <View style={{ width: '50%'}}>

              <Card
                title='STACKOVERFLOW'
                image={require('../imagenes/imagen2.jpg')}
              >
              </Card>

              </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.ProductosCategoriaPadre}>
              <View style={{ width: '50%'}}>
              <Card
                title='STACKOVERFLOW'
                image={require('../imagenes/imagen2.jpg')}
              >
              </Card>

              </View>

              <View style={{ width: '50%'}}>

              <Card
                title='STACKOVERFLOW'
                image={require('../imagenes/imagen2.jpg')}
              >
              </Card>

              </View>
            </View>

        </ScrollView>
    );
```

You can see the card here in a image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to add a styling for the container to get rid of the spacing, like this:

```
<Card containerStyle={{padding: 0}}>
```

Comment: Adding the containerStyle and leave the image from the Props of the card solved the problem. Thank you!